# Posting a comment results in a blank page in iOS app

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app

When submitting a comment on any post, the page will become blank and stay that way. Occasionally it *may* reload the post, but in order to see the comment you have to go to the previous page *and then* back into the post.

Example:

> [image: Blank page]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone10,3
- OS Version: iOS Version 12.1.2 (Build 16C101)

Comment: @Glorfindel ah yep ya got me there. Shame development is on hiatus - you’d think a website full of professional developers would be able to maintain a good quality app.